# Formula needed for merge field

Tags: formula, email-template, merge-field

Right now I have a picklist field the I want to be used in an Email Template.

The picklist values are "Monday, January 17th 5:30 PM" and "Saturday, March 18th 10:00 AM".

The formula I have of now is `{!MID(Contact.Date__c,1,LEN(Contact.Date__c) - 9)}` which takes 9 characters from the right side and cuts it off which works for the Saturday, March 18th 10:00 AM but not for the other date.

How do I create a formula that is dynamic so the merge field works for both pick list values?

EX.  If the user selects Monday, January 17th 5:30 PM it should return Monday, January 17th and if the user selects Saturday, March 18th 10:00 AM it should return March 18th 10:00AM.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Datetime` type fields to store the value? Then you could do `DATEVALUE(Datetime_Field__c)`.

Comment: This is a specific case.  I wish I could use a DATETIME field :(

Comment: Are these two fixed values and would return as that example?

Comment: check your example, I think there something wrong in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will work for you. It will search for `:`, take the position and return the trimmed value.

```
{!TRIM(MID(ContactDate__c,1,FIND(":", ContactDate__c )-3))}
```

Example

`Wednesday, March 18th 1:00 AM` returns `Wednesday, March 18th`

`Saturday, March 18th 10:00 AM` returns `Saturday, March 18th`

`Thursday, March 6th 2:00 AM` returns `Thursday, March 6th`